# Is eating at a restaurant that sells alcohol impermissible?

Tags: halal-haram, business, alcohol

If you, nor anyone you are with drinks alcohol but you are still paying a seller of alcohol (by buying food, non-alcoholic drinks etc) is that permissible?

Comment: The money he returns to you is haram and it is better not to do so. You are encouraged not to eat but it is not haram. (I will need a reference to answer. Searching....)

Comment: @user689, "The money he returns to you is haram" <- this did not make sense. In any transaction (assuming it is valid), the money returned is never haraam, regardless of the other party's source of income.

Comment: I agree with @user689, but even if the money is not declared as haram by scholars, then we are still indirectly contributing to a haram business. I think to act more responsibly is not to pay such mixed businesses at all.

Comment: Conversely,  I am giving them halal money which they would otherwise not receive ...

Comment: I think we can have food in restro and bars only important is we do not intake any alcoholic beverage and food served is halal. Secondly we most off the time pay by our credit or debit card, hence there is no way to take return money from Hotel. what ever you are paying for halal food and not against islam. Concentrate on halal food thats more important.

Answer (score 1):

> And let there be [arising] from you a nation inviting to [all that is]
>   good, enjoining what is right and forbidding what is wrong, and those
>   will be the successful. http://tanzil.net/#3:104

And:

> ... do not cooperate in sin and aggression. And fear Allah; indeed,
>   Allah is severe in penalty. http://tanzil.net/#5:2

It is obligatory for any Muslim to forbid what is wrong. Forbidding has different steps. The lowest steps are any action that the seller understand this is an evil action. For example by fret or by not buying or by any other similar action. These are lowest steps of forbidding what is wrong (in view of Islam). Buying from such a seller has conflict by this command of Quran. There are next advanced steps that need more power.

Also buying anything from a seller is a kind of financial supporting and cooperating him in his business. And because cooperating in sin is banned in Islam so financially supporting a sin business is forbidden.